# 404 page not found on every page - Laravel on Hostgator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to push a Laravel project to production on Hostgator.

I followed this tutorial. Only the last step, changing one line on paths.php I couldn't accomplish because this file do not exists anymore on Laravel: `http://shincoding.com/laravel/installing-configuring-laravel-shared-hosting/`

I put all my project files on `root/quasenerd_base/quase-nerd`, except the content of the public folder, which I moved to `root/public_html`.

I successfully change the path on index.php to the quasenerd_base folder:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../quasenerd_base/quase-nerd/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../quasenerd_base/quase-nerd/bootstrap/app.php';
```

When I access the url http://quasenerd.com.br, I can see my main layout. But it won't load the @section of the page.

In addition, any other url that I try to access returns a 404 page not found. (for example, /login). Apparently I can't access any of my views.

I tryed to add to my index.php:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__;
});
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I have one project on shared hosting and I use this tutorial: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQMZld0Iroo&t=8s)

I hope it will help you.